# Requesting Files from asp.net Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have a Asp.net page from which you are able to upload a picture that I need in code-behind to process and upload. Now if I try to fetch all uploaded files with  `Request.Files` i get a count of 0. If i check with javascript then it does tell me there is a file so how can i get that File in Code-behind?

Asp.net Code

```
<div class="custom-file">
   <input type="file" ID="FileUploadPictureStudent" class="custom-file-input"
   aria-describedby="FileUploadPictureStudent"name="FileUploadPictureStudent" runat="server"
   onchange="fileUploadhandeler(this);" />
   <asp:Label runat="server" class="custom-file-label" for="FileUploadPictureStudent" Text="Choose file" ID="Fileuploadhelper"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Vb.Net Code

```
Dim HelperLabel = Request.Files.Count.ToString()
```

Output page is 0

Output Javascript with Command `document.getElementById('FormViewAddStudent_FileUploadPictureStudent').files` in the console

```
FileList {0: File, length: 1, item: function} = $1
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the `<asp:FileUpload>` control instead?  (Also, just to make sure, you're not using a `<asp:UpdatePanel>` because you can't send files that way)

Comment: Yeah I did try it but with the same result. I am using a `<asp:UpdatePanel>` so guess that's why its not letting me get the file. Is there a way to use the `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and still get the file? because even when I tried to use the `<asp:FileUpload>` and check with the `FileUpload.HasFile` it returned False.

Comment: No, sorry, it's one of the restrictions of the updatepanel

Comment: Oh well, thanks anyway for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, the OP has confirmed they are trying to use the file upload within an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as the UpdatePanel uses AJAX to transfer data, and files cannot be part of that for browser security reasons.

Your main option is to make the page do a full post-back when uploading the file (using a `<Triggers><asp:PostBackTrigger>`), although I fully understand if that would not make a great UI.

Another option would be to have the file-upload in a separate `.aspx` file and have that display onscreen via an `<iframe>`... although again, this comes with a number of disadvantages.